# Microsoft.XNA инициализируется через раз в Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, xna, monogame

У меня есть проект игры на MonoGame. Usings:

```
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
```

Иногда студия видит Xna, иногда нет. Если не видит, я перезагружаю ее и все работает. Еще раз перезагружаю - снова баги. XNA [отсюда](https://flatredball.com/visual-studio-2019-xna-setup/). Что делать?

Comment: Что значит `не видит` и `снова баги`? Дополните вопрос деталями.

Comment: `не видит` - В пространстве имен Microsoft отсутствует определение Xna
`снова баги` - В пространстве имен Microsoft отсутствует определение Xna

Comment: Разработка XNA давно прекращена. Может, стоит обратить внимание на что-то более новое?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, Разработка XNA действительно давно прекращена, но ей на замену пришел MonoGame, который практически полностью копирует API этого фреймворка, с точностью до названий неймспейсов. От этого в будущем планируют уходнить, но сейчас для доступа к типам из MonoGame нужно использовать пространство имен `Microsoft.Xna.Framework`. Такие дела.